# Words for different types of leatherworking

Tags: vocabulary, archaicisms

I'm looking for as many words (and corresponding definitions) as I can find for different specific types of leatherworking.  Archaic words are fine, even preferred.  Of particular interest is a single word for repairs performed by cutting away damaged areas and stitching together with lanyard, if available.  I'm looking for words related to leather *crafting* and *repair*, not so much production.

Multi-word terms that aren't specific to leatherwork or may only be read as specific to leatherwork in context (like "rip work" for the specific term I describe above) are probably not useful to me.

Comment: To clarify: are you looking for specific operations (*skiving*, *stamping*, *tooling*, etc.), or the various types of jobs a saddler or cobbler might take in?

Comment: @Stan Rogers: Specific operations; your examples are definitely in the class of things I'm looking for.

Comment: @Stan Rogers: I've put a bounty on this question now.  If you put those terms in an answer you'd be the front-runner. :)

Comment: ... and I'd also be at the extreme edge of my expertise. I worked for a cobbler for a short time, but since English was not his first language, all I learned was the names of current materials and machines for ordering purposes (and how to swear profusely in Pugliese). As a *mangiacake* (the Italian-Canadian derogatory equivalent of WASP) I wasn't entitled to learn the craft, and what I would have learned wouldn't have been the older English vocabulary. I don't want to be responsible for blatant anachronisms in your work.

Comment: @Stan Rogers: I'd be interested in whatever you've got, really.  The work in question is one where I can easily justify blatant anachronisms by personal fiat (the world history is what I say it is), so that's all good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lacing - a way of joining two pieces of leather with thin strips

saddle-stitch - a specific type of stitch used when both sides of the seam is exposed, like the edges of a saddle

skiving - thinning the leter at the edges to avoid a double layer at a seam

tooling - using a variety of methods/tools to impress designs into a piece of leather for decoration (much like copper tooling)

Oh, there was a Inuit one for softening the leather by having old women chew it - (I'm not being sexist or agest - the word is that specific ...) but I forget it - any Inuit leather worker would probably know it though.

Answer (score 7):

Repair terms seem few, but here are some leather working terms:

- barkened, tanned
- barkometer, instrument for testing tanning solutions
- box-grain, a grain put into leather where lines are crossed
- catechu, a tanning material
- chagrin or shagreen, a leather with a rough surface
- chamar, an (east) Indian leather worker
- chuckler, an (east) Indian leather worker
- clout-leather, leather for shoe mending
- codder, leather worker or saddler
- cordwainer leather worker or shoemaker
- cordwainery, shoemaker's work
- crimp, to bend or mold leather, as in saddle making
- cuir-bouilli, soaked leather molded into some shape which is retained when dry
- currier, someone who dresses or colors leather
- dub, to rub grease into leather
- dubbing or dubbin, grease to apply to leather
- fellmonger, a dealer or worker of hides
- fisher, a tanner's implement
- fluff, to buff leather
- footing, material for footwear
- frieze, an imperfection in leather
- frizz, to rub leather to smooth and soften
- frot, to soften leather by rubbing
- grainer, a tool to impart a grain in leather
- grindery, tools & materials of leather workers
- hidebound, edged with leather
- hided, made of twisted hide
- jacked, hardened, as in leather
- kench, a box to hold salted seal skins
- leathern, made of leather
- mace, mallet to beat leather
- moellon, a wax for leather
- mulled, treated to make softer
- pannus corium, leather for footwear uppers.
- patch leather. leather for patching
- pebbling, using a roller to make an indented surface on leather
- pommel, ribbed wooden tool to improve leather
- pricker, tool to put spaced holes, as for sewing
- Rexine, an imitation leather (proprietary)
- riempie, leather strip used in chair backs, etc.
- sammy, to dampen or dry leather slightly
- scoring iron, tool to run lines on leather
- shaganappi, cord made from rawhide
- shamoy, to work grease into leather
- skiver, worker who splits leather
- sleeker, tool to smooth leather
- slicker, tool to smooth leather
- smoothing, an iron to smooth leather
- snuff, to curry or smooth leather
- spetch, a leather patch for mending leather items
- stamper, tool to beat leather with
- stark, tool to dress leather
- stitch-wheel, tool to put spaced holes (pricker)
- zug, a waterproof leather

Also, there may be a bunch of unusual terms for tanning materials and types of leather.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Leatherworking

This provides additional wikipedia links to more detailed explanations about leather carving, swivel knives, stamping, dying, tanning, etc.

Answer (score -1):

No one has said cobbler -
A shoe maker - most shoes are leather ??  Hmmm might not be specific, a dutch shoemaker could work in wood I guess.

Comment: Yeah, fabric is used in shoes a lot too.  It's not really leatherworking-specific.

Answer (score -2):

I could only help with some adjectives :

1)leather

2)dermal

3)leathern

4)dermic

5)dermatic , See if this can help :)